# Example of such an affine scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-schemes

I am stucking on construction an affine $\Bbb Z$-scheme $X$ such that $X_{\Bbb F_2}$ is irreducible but not reduced, $X_{\Bbb F_3}$ is reduced but not irreducible, and $X_\Bbb C$ is reduced and irreducible.

That is I need to find a proper number of variables and a relation set $T$ such that for $Spec(\Bbb Z[x_s:s\in S]/\langle T\rangle)$, such that if we replace the scaler $\Bbb Z$ by $\Bbb Z_2,\Bbb Z_3$ and $\Bbb C$, we have the affine scheme with desired property.

I cannot find a way that these conditions could be satisfied simutanously. Any ideas for that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[x, y] / \langle 2x^3 + 3x^2 - 2x - 6y \rangle )$ should work.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try just taking a disjoint union of schemes $A\coprod B\coprod C$, where $A$ is a scheme over $\mathbb{F}_2$, $B$ is a scheme over $\mathbb{F}_3$, and $C$ is a scheme over $\mathbb{Z}[1/6]$.

A specific example that works is hidden below.

> Let $A=\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2)$, $B=\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{F}_3^2$, and $C=\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}[1/6]$, and let $X=A\coprod B\coprod C$.  Explicitly, $X=\operatorname{Spec} (\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2)\times \mathbb{F}_3^2\times\mathbb{Z}[1/6])$.

Comment: Thanks! I have a further question: It seems quite natural. But it takes somework to translate a product ring to a presentation in the form $\Bbb Z[x_s|s\in S]/\langle T\rangle$. Since both reduced and irreducible are defined in the sense of ideals(reduced: $\mathcal O(X)$ is a reduced ring; irreducible $X=Z_I$ for $\sqrt{I}$ strongly irreducible). May I please ask if some common result is used here to see this scheme indeed satisfies the reduced/irreducible properties in language of ideals?

Comment: It is very awkward to define things in terms of presentations and I would not recommend using those definitions unless they are actually useful for what you are doing.  Instead you can just use the fact that tensor products of rings distribute over finite direct products, so to find $X_{\mathbb{F}_2}$ and so on you can just tensor each factor separately.